# How to "Snoop" a ContextMenu?

Tags: c#, wpf, snoop

I have a `ContextMenu` that uses a `CompositeCollection` for its ItemsSource. One of the items (the one that is in a bound collection, as opposed to hard-coded) is displayed differently from the rest.

I didn't see anything obvious in the XAML as to why this is, so I thought I would use Snoop to look at the actual rendered style (and find the difference). However, whenever I activate the Snoop window to look for the Context Menu, it closes the menu!

Is there a way to use Snoop (or a similar tool) to inspect a `ContextMenu`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whenever user performs any action outside of an opened `ContextMenu` will get closed. This is default behaviour of the `ContextMenu`, But still `Snoop` provides all the informations about the `ContextMenu` and it's `MenuItems` in the VisualTreeView of the Snoop window on Left side. If you want to snoop a specift `ContextMenuItem`

- Attach your application with the Snoop
- Press Shift+Ctrl and mouse over to the `ContextMenuItem` you want to snoop which shows a Red border. Also the same control will be selected in the Treeview of the Snoop window

Answer (score 8):

- Select your WPF application in Snoop
- Open the context menu
- Press Shift+Ctrl and move the mouse pointer to one of the context menu items.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the quick, easy to understand response.